# Double-clicking to open a file on a standalone matlab application

Tags: matlab, user-interface, double-click

I have timeseries files with their own extension (.Z4R). I have compile my matlab GUI that read them.

Right now I load these files from the GUI (look for the path...). I wondering if it's possible to just double-click on the .Z4R in order to load it into my program.

---

Thank you.

I understand the window part. 
Where I don't know it is about this command line that accept the input (Z4D) when the GUI .exe starts. How do I know the path of the double-clicked file.

Thanks
Marc

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this via Windows file association (assuming you are running windows).

You'll need to check the command line arguments of your app and open supplied Z4R files as appropriate.

Have a look on google to see how to set-up [file associations](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20extension%20association)

If your compiled Matlab GUI was created using the Matlab tool guide, you should have a function

```
 function YourProgramName_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
```

varargin should contain the filename you double clicked on.